# while scheduling SSIS package in sql 2012 64 bit i am getting this error

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, package

> Executed as user: ASIAPACIFIC\nshanm. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute
>   Package Utility  Version 10.0.1600.22 for 64-bit  Copyright (C)
>   Microsoft Corp 1984-2005. All rights reserved.    Started:  2:45:01 PM
>   Error: 2016-08-29 14:45:01.18     Code: 0xC001700A     Source:
>   Description: The version number in the package is not valid. The
>   version number cannot be greater than current version number.  End
>   Error  Error: 2016-08-29 14:45:01.21     Code: 0xC0016020     Source: 
>   Description: Package migration from version 6 to version 3 failed with
>   error 0xC001700A "The version number in the package is not valid. The
>   version number cannot be greater than current version number.".  End
>   Error  Error: 2016-08-29 14:45:01.21     Code: 0xC0010018     Source: 
>   Description: Error loading value "6" from node
>   "DTS:Property".  End Error  Could not load package
>   "C:\ssis\fileupload\fileupload\Package.dtsx" because of error
>   0xC0010014.  Description: The package failed to load due to error
>   0xC0010014 "One or more error occurred. There should be more specific
>   errors preceding this one that explains the details of the errors.
>   This message is used as a return value from functions that encounter
>   errors.". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.  Source:
>   Started:  2:45:01 PM  Finished: 2:45:01 PM  Elapsed:  0.125 seconds. 
>   The package could not be loaded.  The step failed.

I try to schedule SSIS package in SQL Server Agent but I am getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the old version of the DTEXEC is picked up by SQL Server instead of the new one.

Refer Link: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ramoji/2008/12/24/package-migration-from-version-3-to-version-2-failed-with-error-0xc001700a-the-version-number-in-the-package-is-not-valid-the-version-number-cannot-be-greater-than-current-version-number/